# Displaying an image and automatically re-size it

Tags: qt, qt4, qpixmap, qlabel

I can't quite figure out what the best way of displaying an image is in my particular case, so hopefully someone on here has a few tips.

I want to display an image that gets re-sized automatically to fit inside the space that is available. I currently do this by creating a class derived from QLabel that implements `void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent*)` where I do a `QPixmap::scaled` to re-size the image. The problem is that this only works when the widget is enlarged because the widget doesn't get a resizeEvent when I try to make the widget smaller. I guess that because I set the image to the same size as the widget, it isn't allowed to be sized smaller again? I guess I could try to create a smaller image therefor introducing a sort of "border" around the image which would perhaps allow re-size events to occur when making the area smaller. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

*resizeEvent* is sent whenever size is changed. It doesn't matter whether it is enlarged or not.
But you can set Policy and Max/Min size to constraint widget in shrinking/enlarging. So if you have your widget not getting *resizeEvent* AND it doesn't shrink either, then look at your size policy and min width/height. If it shrinks but you doesn't have *resizeEvent* then you have some error in you logic, I believe.

Alternatively you can use *paintEvent* for image painting and use QWidget::rect() for your widget width/height.

Comment: it doesn't shrink (and hence it isn't getting a resizeEvent) .. I'll have a look at this resize policy

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the [size policy](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qsizepolicy.html) of the label to QSizePolicy::Preferred.

Have a look at size policies in general.